# How to replace block text with Sed in Linux?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file I would like to

- replace a portion with some spaces
- cut to a specific position

Easier to understand with a diagram:

[image]

I tried that without success:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)161$/ /" $FICSUP$EXTMOD
```

Data:

```
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDCP                    H125,45                                                                                                                                                       
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDRTT                   H170                                                                                                                                                          
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDRTTN-1                H130                                                                                                                                                          
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDCPA                   H200                                                                                                                                                          
CRE                           M                    0123457                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDCP                    H124,45
```

Comment: Add example input file as text, explicitly mention the separator/type of formatting the file uses.

Comment: It's not very clear at all. What's the significance of `161` in the pattern? Do you want to cut the spaces before the devanagari (?) string or truncate the line? Under what conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to:

1. Remove all the numbers and commas in the last field at the end of the field (prior to spaces)
2. Truncate the spaces in the fixed length field at the end with smaller fixed length spaces

Using your data as input here is what the result looks like
Remove the "."s in the regex with however many spaces you need.
I have used "." to make the whitespace visible.

```
$ cat data | sed -r "s/[0-9,]* *$/..................../"
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDCP                    H....................
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDRTT                   H....................
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDRTTN-1                H....................
CRE                           M                    0123456                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDCPA                   H....................
CRE                           M                    0123457                                                         01/01/2016                         ZDCP                    H....................
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
sed "s/[0-9]\+[,]*[0-9]*$/         /g" your_file.txt
```

This replaces every number (including the comma) at the end of the line with 8 spaces.